# Node NPM modules... compatability with older Node 4?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

There's a lot of modern JS around with ES6 and that is supported in Node 6/7

But what does that mean if you are running Node 4?

If an NPM module is written in ES6, does NPM require it to compile down to an older more compatible version of JS?

Asking because I'm investigating AWS Lambda, which runs Node 4... does that greatly restrict my NPM module choices?